# Old post shows up in low quality post after edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I'm wondering if it's intended behavior.

I was looking at the "Low quality posts" review queue and was reviewing an answer. I figured that the answer was quite dated. Someone just improved the formatting. Now it popped up in the queue again. Is this intended behavior?

[The post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496152/how-to-create-tablespace-with-multiple-datafiles). It's the answer from June 2012.

As it was a "me too" post I was wondering as well if I should have clicked the "recommend deletion" button for not adding further value, but copying someone else's answer. Maybe there should be links explaining when to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Only [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496152/how-to-create-tablespace-with-multiple-datafiles/11271841#11271841) to the post in question was reviewed multiple times.

It appeared once in the [Late Answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/844485), then once in the [Suggested Edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/850818), and then once in the [Low Quality Posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/850831).

This is by design.